# Have two different TensorFlow's, how to uninstall both completely?

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow

I have TensorFlow 0.12 that I built from source for GPU support a few months. There was some problems with it that I solved right now but in the downtime I'd installed TensorFlow 1.0.1 using `pip install tensorflow-gpu`. I want to know how exactly to uninstall both and start over by installing TF 1.0. What else do I need to do other than deleting `/home/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/`? This is the output when I use the following commands:

```
$ pip show tensorflow
 Name: tensorflow
 Version: 0.12.0rc1
 Summary: TensorFlow helps the tensors flow
 Home-page: http://tensorflow.org/
 Author: Google Inc.
 Author-email: opensource@google.com
 License: Apache 2.0
 Location: /home/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages
 Requires: mock, numpy, protobuf, wheel, six


$ pip show tensorflow-gpu
 Name: tensorflow-gpu
 Version: 1.0.1
 Summary: TensorFlow helps the tensors flow
 Home-page: http://tensorflow.org/
 Author: Google Inc.
 Author-email: opensource@google.com
 License: Apache 2.0
 Location: /home/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages
 Requires: mock, numpy, protobuf, wheel, six
```

On navigating to the tensorflow-gpu folder in site-packages I found some few files, mostly text

```
$ cd anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_gpu-1.0.1.dist-info/
$ ls
  DESCRIPTION.rst  entry_points.txt  METADATA  metadata.json  RECORD  top_level.txt  WHEEL
```

Comment: Did it work or not?

Answer (score 2):

`pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu` and `pip uninstall tensorflow` should do it. Otherwise, you can also completely remove and reinstall anaconda to start from scratch.